Meaning of 烟花 , both in general and in a poem by Li Bai
A verse of a well-known poem by Li Bai (李白) reads:
烟花三月下扬州
I'm struggling with the translation of the characters 烟花.
Should they be read as a single word ("fireworks") or as a composition of terms ("perfume of blossom"), or something else?
What are the meaning of 烟花 also in other contexts?

Here's a modern song based on that -- https://youtu.be/Cs6ZUESJuHgsi=pIdwEe8SWKmcgAWv

There are sites explaining classical poems
《黄鹤楼送孟浩然之广陵》

故人西辞黄鹤楼，烟花三月下扬州。


孤帆远影碧空尽，唯见长江天际流。


烟花：形容柳絮如烟、鲜花似锦的春天景物 - smoke and flower: describe the spring scenery of catkins like smoke and flowers like brocade.

Another source 扬州故事

在这个春天里，应该到扬州去看一看，这个时候正是那里最美的时候。那里的天气，那里的[烟柳]，那里的[琼花]，都带着浓浓的春的气息。- In this spring, you should go to Yangzhou to see it. This is the most beautiful time there. The weather, the [smokey willows], and the [viburnums]. All have a strong sense of spring.

游记：江南三月烟柳


As no more than one answer can be marked as "accepted", I accept this one because it seems the most exhaustive to me, at the moment; personally I'd also accept the answers provided by other users, too (upvoted them, indeed!).

Personally, I like the ability to evoke such descriptive atmosphere in a such intense way, just using just few characters. This is one of the reasons I find Chinese poetry so fascinating.


Should they be read as a single word

no
read it as “煙波” + “花”, roughly “mist / fog over water” & flowers [on shore]
have fun :)

What is the meaning of 水巷孑蠻? Lonely barbarian? From a poem or whence?

@Pedroski, well, when i needed a user name for stackexchange, i was still living in . . . 水+巷 —> 港  the rest, you get it  now, 天涯隨寓 lah

@水巷孑蠻 "lonely barbarian from Hong Kong (lane of water)", then?

@水巷孑蠻 thanks for your answer, by the way!

In general, 烟花 means 1. fireworks 2. prostitution.
In poems:

烟花 - 雾霭中的花朵 (Flower in mist). It indirectly described the poetical spring scenery in 扬州.

烟花三月 - In the flower flourish misty March..... paints the picture below.


thanks for your answer! Your explanation, together with the picture, is very enlightening.
